# Show that $\{x_1x_2 + x_2x_3+ x_3x_4 =c\}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$ and is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb S^1$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism, submanifold

Let $c \neq 0$ be a real number. We define $M_c$ as
$$M_c = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb R^4|x_1x_2 + x_2x_3+ x_3x_4 =c \}.$$

> (1) Show $M_c$ is submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$.
>
> (2) Show $M_c$ is diffeomorphism to $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb S^1$.

My approach (I cannot solve neither):

(1) I consider $f:\mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R$, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)= x_1x_2 + x_2x_3+ x_3x_4$. Also $df = (x_2,x_1+x_3,x_2+x_4,x_3)$.

(2) I tried to construct smooth map from $M_c$ to $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb S^1$ and inverse function of it. But I cannot.

[Edited]

From Mike F's approach, $M_c$ is diffeomorphic to Special linear group $SL(2,R)$. Generally $SL(n,R) \simeq SO(n,R) \times R^{(n+2)(n-1)/2}$ and $SO(2,R) \simeq S^1$. Hence $M_c \simeq SL(2,R) \simeq S^1 \times R^2$.

Comment: For (1) why do you calculate $df$?

Comment: For (1) you are almost done. It is clear that $df$ attains full rank (rank 1) except at the origin. But from the equation, the origin is not a point in this set. Now appeal to the regular value theorem.

Comment: For (2) try completing the square on the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion, though perhaps not the most efficient approach. Define new coordinates
\begin{align*}
y_1 = x_1 + x_3 && y_2 = \frac{1}{c} x_2 && y_3 = -x_3 && y_4=\frac{1}{c} x_4
\end{align*}
Note this coordinate change is mediated by an invertible 4-by-4 matrix. In the new coordinate system, the equation under consideration becomes
$$y_1 y_2 - y_3y_4 = 1$$
So, the problem is tantamount to showing that the set of matrices $\begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_3 \\ y_4 & y_2\end{bmatrix}$ whose determinant is $1$ is a submanifold of the space of all 2-by-2 matrices which is moreover diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$. In my opinion, this translated form of the problem is a better use of your time.